# How to Upload image in Website odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9, odoo-website

I am working on Hr_Recruitment module.I have added a binary image field for HR->Application.I am trying to add functionality for external user to fill the job application them self through website.I have added name,email,phone,resume attachment fields in website for Job application.when they click on submit, it is updating in HR->Job Application Form.But Image field is not getting updated in Application.When opening the job application It is showing message like "Could not show the selected image".How to solve this issue?

controller/main.py

```
if post.get('image',False):
            image = request.registry['ir.attachment']
            name = post.get('image').filename      
            file = post.get('image')
                attach = file.stream
                file.show()

                f = attach.getvalue()

                webbrowser.open(image)
            attachment_id = Attachments.create(request.cr, request.uid, {
                    'name': image,
                    'res_name': image,
                    'res_model': 'hr.applicant',
                    'res_id': applicant_id,
                        'datas': base64.decodestring(str(res[0])),
                        'datas_fname': post['image'].filename,
        }, request.context)

views/templates.xml

<div t-attf-class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="image">Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
                                        <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
                            <input id="uploadImage" name="image" type="file" class="file" multiple="true" data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true" data-show-preview="true" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>
                    </div>
                     </div>
```

[image: Application Form in website page]
[image: HR->Application Form]

Answer (score 3):

Add the image field as shown below in your XML template:

```
<img itemprop="image" style="margin-top: -53px; margin-left:19px; width:80px;" class="img img-responsive" t-att-src="website.image_url(partner, 'image', None if product_image_big else '300x300')"/>
<input class="input-file profileChooser" id="fileInput" type="file" name="ufile" onchange="validateProfileImg();"/>
```

remove the unnecessary attributes for you.

And in your controller function, you can get the value from the image fields as:

```
vals = {}
if post['ufile']:
    vals.update({'image': base64.encodestring(post['ufile'].read())})
request.registry['res.partner'].write(cr, uid, [partner_id], vals)
```

The above code works for me, I have been using this to update partner images from ODOO website.

Comment: I tried this Gopakumar, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you get any error? Which Odoo version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am using odoo13 and I used this format to upload an image from the website to the respartner form view:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
   <label for="image_1920" class="form-label">Passport Photo*</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image_1920" name="image_1920" required="1" />
</div>
```

```py
import base64

    @http.route('/registered', auth='public', methods=['GET', 'POST'], website=True)
    def registration_submit(self, *args, **kw):
        image = kw.get('image_1920', False)

        kw.update({
            'free_member': True,
            'image_1920': base64.encodestring(image.read()) if image else False
        })
        member = request.env['res.partner'].sudo().create(kw)
```